# How to trim/cut few seconds audio in react js?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

I'm working with react and need to use audio files to play but in that while looing sounds it get pause of 1 second. if anyone knows how to loop it without pause? please let me know solution if you have.
How to trim or cut last few seconds of audio in react using html tag  ?. I got solution using ffmpeg, but not got how to use it in react. do you know? or any other solution?

Comment: Can you [show an example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68563545/edit) (add code) of how your audio is being looped? Show us testable code that recreates your problem.

Comment: const handlePlay = (song) =>{
        var time;
        setShow(!show)
        if(!isPlaying){
            setIsPlaying(true)
            audio.play()
            console.log("duration: ",audio.duration);
            time = audio.currentTime/audio.duration
            if(time === audio.duration-1){
               // audio.play();
            }
        }
        if(isPlaying){
            setIsPlaying(false)
            audio.pause()
        }
        audio.loop = true;
    }<audio ref={audioRef} src={song} controls></audio>

Comment: Above given the code  in button tag onclick event the handlePlay function is added

Comment: When Sound comes to end then it take 1 sec pause and plays next cycle. But I don't want pause there. What to do?